# Onedrive SDK - Authentication Token is getting nil value

Tags: ios, authentication, token, onedrive

During OneDrive Authentication using  OneDrive SDK for iOS,  after the authentication screen,  At times, the highlighted values of “response” objects are NIL .  I’m not sure why this is happening.
Out of 10 trials, 2-3 times the values inside the Repsonse object is NIL. So this is landing the App in crash.Any guess why this is happening? May be because of poor network?  Or any other thing I might have missed? In Onedrive SDK - LiveAuthRequest.m file has the following lines of code.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    id response = [LiveAuthHelper readAuthResponse:self.tokenResponseData];

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[LiveConnectSession class]])
    {
        _client.session = response;     => Crash is Happening Here*
        self.session = response;
        [self updateStatus:AuthTokenRetrieved];
    }
    else
    {
        self.error = response;
        [self updateStatus:AuthFailed];
    }   

    self.tokenResponseData = nil;
    self.tokenConnection = nil;
}
```

**The Response from the Onedrive Server side.  1. authentication_Token, 2.refreshToken, 3.scope 4.expires_in 5.tokenType"**, 
iOS version:5.1.1
OneDrive SDK Version:5.0 
[image]   [image]

Comment: How are you getting id response?

Comment: I am just entering the Credentials, The SDK itself Providing these Response @JeanineMS

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of SDK - v5.6 - since memory issues have been fixed since v5.0: https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS

Comment: Can you confirm with latest version will covered this Error. Actually I am not facing any kind of memory issues. I am facing logging Issue. Can you please read one more time this Question and give me any suggestion to achieve my problem.